# print all but select fields in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a large file with hundreds of columns that I want to remove only the third and fourth columns from and print the rest to a file.  My initial idea was to make an awk script like `awk '{print $1, $2, for (i=$5; i <= NF; i++) print $i }' file > outfile`.  However, this code does not work.

I then tried:

```
awk '{for(i = 1; i<=NF; i++)
if(i == 3 || i == 4) continue
else
print($i)}' file > outfile
```

But this just printed everything out in one field.  It would be possible to split this up into two scripts and combine them with unix `paste` but this seems like something that should be able to be done in one line.

Comment: I have a bunch of awk column filtering functions here if you are interested https://github.com/mhitza/inflated-shell/blob/master/src/filters/input/column

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your first try was pretty close.  Modifying it to use `printf` and including the field separators worked for me:

```
awk '{printf $1FS$2; for (i=5; i <= NF; i++) printf FS$i; print NL }'
```

Comment: NL isn't any standard feature of awk (nor even a non-standard one on any of the 4 implementations I have access to). It's just a regular variable, here uninitialized. The `print NL` ends up printing a newline because it's getting interpreted as `print ""`. `print sjskjsdsj` would have the same result.

Answer (score 16):

What about something like:

```
cat SOURCEFILE | cut -f1-2,5- >> DESTFILE
```

It prints the first two columns, skips the 3rd and 4rth, and then prints from 5 onwards to the end.

Comment: no need to pipe it from cat. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458414/print-all-but-select-fields-in-awk/6458705#6458705

Comment: This is exactly the right answer, thanks! I mean, it doesn't use `awk` as the question requires, but `cut` is a great utility for doing exactly this task.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer *if* what you have is a file with specific column markers. If what you have is the output of a command that has visible columns but no column markers (i.e. it's space-aligned/padded text that looks neat and tabular to a human but isn't csv etc) then this is entirely the wrong answer as it will only work for the rows where the content is the same length and so the "columns" fall in the right place. `cut -c` also works but you need to count your characters. `awk` Just Works™ with space-aligned files.

Answer (score 10):

How about just setting the third and fourth columns to an empty string:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 |
awk -F" " '{ $3="";  $4=""; print}'
```

Comment: But you're still stuck with the delimeters: `echo 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10 | awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} { $3="";  $4=""; print}'`

Comment: Very useful method if you want to preserve the number of columns but just want to disregard the data in it (e.g. to make a CSV a little smaller).

Answer (score 7):

Say you have a *tab* delimited file that looks like the following:

**temp.txt**

> field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6
>   field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6
>   field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6

running the following will remove field 3 and 4 and output to end of line.

`awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"substr($0, index($0,$5))}' temp.txt`

> > field1    field2      field5  field6
> >     field1    field2      field5  field6
> >     field1    field2      field5  field6

My example(s) print to stdout. 
`> newFile` will send stdout to newFile and `>> newFile` will append to newFile.

So you may want to use the following:

`awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"substr($0, index($0,$5))}' temp.txt > newFile.txt`

some will argue for cut

`cut -f1,2,5- temp.txt`

which produce the same output, and cut is great for simplicity, but does not handle inconsistent delimiters. For example mixture of different whitespaces. However, in this case cut may be what you are after.

you could also accomplish this in perl,python,ruby,and many others, but here is the simplest `awk` solution.

Comment: awk is working until content of field 5 is in one of the 4th first field. In this case you cut too soon.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to just set the third and fourth columns to an empty string; but, in addition, field `$1` should be set to itself (`$1=$1`) to make `awk` actually consume the input field separator (delimeter) `:` on the entire current line `$0` in one go.

```
echo 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10 | awk -F: '{ $1=$1; $3=""; $4=""; print $0}'
```

Comment: This works as long as you don't mind having multiple consecutive delimiters in the output. That might be fine in some situations, but not in others.

Answer (score 0):

The hard but generic way (to forget for a simple oneliner)

```
awk -v "Exclude=3:4:5" '
   # load exclusion
   BEGIN{
      Count=split(Exclude, aTmp, ":")
      for( i = 1; i <= Count; i++) aExc[ aTmp[ i]]=1
      }

   # treat each line, taking only wanted field
   {
    Result=""
    for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
       # field to take ?
       if( ! aExc[ i]) {
         # first element or add a separator before
         if( Result != "") Result=Result OFS $i
          else Result=$i
         }
       }

    print Result
   }' YourFile
```

- you can specify any field that you want to exclude

  - fill field index in varaible *Exclude* separate by a `:` in first line
- separator are correct in place an quantity
- code is "expanded" for better understanding
- the final result is not exactly as input (without excluded field) because the output separator is used instead of original separator (ex 2 space or a tab is changed to 1 space with default behaviour)